# Animation on UIButton's Image stops when another UIButton Background color is changed

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton, core-animation

Context: 
Swift 4

There is a stackView of UIButtons, that exists in a scrollView. If a button has an image, it animates infinitely. Once another button is tapped in the stackView, the animation stops. I've tried running on the main thread, and `commitAnimations` (which isn't recommended) - neither have worked.

The code is proprietary, so I can't paste it, but here's the idea:

This is the code that animates the button's image:

```
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
                view.alpha = 0
            }, completion: nil)
```

In the function that selects another button in the scrollView, a few things are happening:

- `scrollToItem` is being called on a collectionView
- `scrollRectToVisible` is being called
- Some properties like `backgroundColor` are being called on views

**Edit**

After trying to narrow the cause of the problem, I've found that the issue is updating another button's background color, not when a scrollView scrolls.

If I can provide more context, please let me know!

Comment: You can provide the code that animates the buttons, and the function called on click of a button too, that would help

Comment: @DamienBannerot Just updated, please let me know if there's anything else I can give you! Thanks!